# Trigger Lottie animation on hover of parent container Avada

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lottie

The latest version of Avada has the ability to integrate Lottie animations. One of the triggers you can use is to hover over the graphic and it will animate. This is great but ideally, it would be better to hover over the container that the animation is inside. Is there a class I can add to the container? While this happening I noticed that the animation stops on mouse leave, is there any way to make it finish the loop too? There is a sample on Avadas website:

https://avada.theme-fusion.com/design-elements/lottie-animation-element/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else needs this, I just stretched the outer element of the svg to the full size of my container.

```
.container .fusion-lottie-animation {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 85%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -20px;
    padding: 20px;
}


.cards-home .fusion-lottie-animation svg {
    width: 150px!important;
    height: 100px!important;
}
```